# I am trying to build CS50 PSET 1 problem: CASH with a for loop, but I am not getting any result

Tags: c, for-loop, return, cs50

Kindly help me understand issues with my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main(void)
{   
    int cents;
    do
    {
        cents = get_int("Cash owed (in cents): ");

    } while (cents < 0);

    int quarter, dime, nickel, penny;
    
    for (quarter = 0; cents>=25; quarter++)
    {
        cents = cents - 25;
    }
    return quarter;
    for (dime = 0; cents>=10; dime++)
    {
        cents = cents - 10;
    }
    return dime;
    for (nickel = 0; cents>=5; nickel++)
    {
        cents = cents - 5;
    }
    return nickel;
    for (penny = 0; cents>=1; penny++)
    {
        cents = cents - 1;
    }
    return penny;
    int coins = quarter + dime + nickel + penny;
    printf("Total coins %i: ", coins);
}
```

I expected it to give no of coins but instead the program does not move forward after obtaining user input.

Comment: The problem is in `return quarter;` at line 19. Why're you doing that? Everything after it is dead code.

Comment: Include `\n` at the end of the format string to `printf()`, or call `fflush(stdout)` after `printf()`.

Comment: The problem statement asked you to implement `get_cents()`, `calculate_quarters()`, `calculate_nickels()`, `calculate_dimes()`, `calculate_pennies()`, and return the results from them. I do not see that in any part of your code.